# Replace BuildAll by Makefile

Tags: c, compilation, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to replace BuildAll of Eclipse CDT by a Makefile?

I mean I have a Makefile in C and I would buildall from this file. I build a Target in Eclipse to compile but I would use the Ctrl+B to buildall. My environment is Eclipse-Cdt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to use my own makefile. In fact it's very easy. The alone think that I did is to precise the emplacement of the makefile in the build properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in creating a makefile that would invoke other make files.

But achieving interaction between Eclipse and the makefile would be extremely hard.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, you can tell Eclipse CDT to use your own makefile instead of generating one. And you can tell Eclispe to use a specific target. So it should be easy.

my2c

Comment: Hi everyone, I found the solution to use my own makefile. In fact it's very easy. The alone think that I did is to precise the emplacement of the makefile in the build properties.